# Json extract unique data - Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am having  a set of request in my Thread Group in which first request will feed inputs for the second request. I am using json extractor (match No.0) to extract the value from the list.  I want  to ensure that  same data extracted in the Thread 1 is not been fetched in the subsequent thread runs. Can you please suggest how handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [JSON Extractor documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

> If the JSON Path query leads to many results, you can choose which one(s) to extract as Variables:
>
> `0` : means **random** (Default Value)

The "random" doesn't guarantee uniqueness so if you need the data to be unique - consider providing an incremented value to this "Match No" field.

Example setup:

1. Given the following JSON

   ```
   {
       "store": {
           "book": [
               {
                   "category": "reference",
                   "author": "Nigel Rees",
                   "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                   "price": 8.95
               },
               {
                   "category": "fiction",
                   "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                   "title": "Sword of Honour",
                   "price": 12.99
               },
               {
                   "category": "fiction",
                   "author": "Herman Melville",
                   "title": "Moby Dick",
                   "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                   "price": 8.99
               },
               {
                   "category": "fiction",
                   "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                   "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                   "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                   "price": 22.99
               }
           ],
           "bicycle": {
               "color": "red",
               "price": 19.95
           }
       },
       "expensive": 10
   }
   ```
2. Let's assume you want to use unique book title, i.e.

   - `Sayings of the Century` - for 1st iteration
   - `Sword of Honour` - for 2nd iteration
   - etc.
3. Amend "Match No" field value to look like:

   ```
   ${__intSum(${__jm__Thread Group__idx},1,)}
   ```

   where `__jm__Thread Group__idx` is a pre-defined variable available since [JMeter 4.0](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-in-jmeter-4) which returns current [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) iteration and [__intSum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__intSum) is the JMeter Function which adds `1` to the iteration number (as it's zero-based)

   the full JSON Extractor configuration would be something like:

   [image]
4. That's basically it, now you have the confidence that the new value is being picked up for each Thread Group iteration, it can be checked using i.e. [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

   [image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for guidance, i tried the step you mentioned and getting the below error:ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error while processing sampler: 'Debug Sampler'.
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "${__jm__Thread Group__idx}"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569) ~[?:1.8.0_181]
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615) ~[?:1.8.0_181]. I am using Jmeter 4.0 only

Comment: What is the name of your Thread Group? If it differs from `Thread Group` you need to amend the variable like `${__jm__put-your-thread-group-name-here__idx}`

Comment: I was able to fix it. Thanks Once again for your support!

Comment: The  logic works  for the loop count but not for the  Number of threads. Eg :if i have 5 threads with one loop count the logic works same as  Match No as 1